# Sum and count in for loop

Tags: shell-script, files, for

I have five files each with a number in the first line.

I am attempting to write a bash script incorporating a for-loop that can calculate both the number (count) of the files and the sum of the numbers within in the files.

This is what I have attempted so far:

```
for file in $* 
do
        $[head -1 $file] 
        echo $(head -1) 
done
```

I am unsure how to incorporate a sum and count element as yet.

Comment: Can you provide example context of file and expected output?

Comment: I am teaching myself for-loops. I have five files labeled file1,..,file5. The first entry of each file is a number. I would like to write a loop that 
a) adds all the numbers up and prints a sum
b) reports the number of files it went through (ie the count).

Answer (score 6):

I guess what you are trying to do can be achieved by this:

```
#!/bin/bash
sum=0
count=0
for file in "$@"
do
        number=$(head -1 "$file")
        count=$((count + 1))
        sum=$((sum + number))
done
echo "The sum of the $count file(s) is: $sum"
```

You just add variables to store the `sum` and the `count` of the files you are working with. You then increase the `count` each time you run through the loop. Also we add the `number` at the beginning line of the file to our `sum`-variable.

Comment: This doesn't work then there's a pipe. Ex: `ls *.count | while read file`

Answer (score 2):

You could also do this with awk, avoiding the need to for `head` for each file:

```
gawk '{count += 1; sum += $1; nextfile} 
      END {printf "count: %d\t sum: %d\n", count, sum}' *
```

The first rule increments the count and sum, and then jumps to the next file, thus ignoring all but the first line of each file. In the `END`, we print out the numbers.

`nextfile` is a GNU thing, it might not work in other versions of `awk`. Another alternative would be to explicitly work only on the first line:

```
awk 'FNR == 1 {count += 1; sum += $1} 
      END {printf "count: %d\t sum: %d\n", count, sum}' *
```

This would however read the files in full, even if it doesn't do anything with the rest of the lines.